# Track the total time the HTMLAudio was playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, time

How could I track for how long was the HTMLAudio playing in total?

What I tried to do is to run the following function each time an audio started to play or paused:

```
let totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
let intervalId = null;

const startedToPlay = function() {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() { ++totalTimeInSeconds; }, 1000);
};
const pausedPlaying = function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

But I am getting a little bit of a difference. The difference is +-20 seconds.

So, what is a better way to do this?

In order to avoid the `x-y problem`: I need this to trigger my own events once the audio played for more than a specified amount of time in total (that means that we can rewind the audio back and forth, but still we are only interested in total time listened and not the length of the audio listened).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to simply set a timeout when they start playing, and clear the timeout when they pause, and update the total time left only on pause.

Something like:

```js
const SECOND = 1000;
let timeLeft = 5 * SECOND;
let startTime = null;
let timeout = null;
let div = document.getElementById('timer')
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
let playing = false;
toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (playing) {
        pausedPlaying();
    } else {
        startedToPlay();
    }
    playing = !playing;
});

const startedToPlay = function() {
    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    timeout = setTimeout(() => alert(), timeLeft);
};

const pausedPlaying = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeLeft -= (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    startTime = null;
};

setInterval(() => div.textContent = startTime ? (timeLeft - ((new Date()).getTime() - startTime)) : timeLeft);
```

```html
<div id="timer">5</div>

<button id="toggle">Start/Stop</button>
```

Note the interval at the bottom is only for updating the displayed time left.